# AngularJS Object not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
 .controller('lineCtrl', function($sessionStorage, $rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $state, $filter, config, $http, SCAN_EVENT, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, ScanService){

        var areaName;
        var lineCounts;

        function filterObjects () {
            switch ($stateParams.area) {

                case 'PW':
                    $scope.items = $filter('filter')($rootScope.runnerItemsPW, {line: $stateParams.line}, true);
                    areaName = "Putwall";
                    lineCounts = $rootScope.lineCountPW;
                    break;
                case 'NC':
                    $scope.items = $filter('filter')($rootScope.runnerItemsNC, {line: $stateParams.line}, true);
                    areaName = "Non-Con";
                    lineCounts = $rootScope.lineCountNC;
                    break;
                case 'RE':
                    $scope.items = $filter('filter')($rootScope.runnerItemsRE, {line: $stateParams.line}, true);
                    areaName = "Receiving";
                    lineCounts = $rootScope.lineCountRE;
                    break;
                case 'SP':
                    $scope.items = $filter('filter')($rootScope.runnerItemsSP, {line: $stateParams.line}, true);
                    areaName = "Singles Pack";
                    lineCounts = $rootScope.lineCountSP;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        filterObjects();

        $rootScope.lineData = {
            position: 1,
            lineNumber: $stateParams.line,
            area: $stateParams.area,
            areaName: areaName,
            lineCounts: lineCounts,
            items: $scope.items
        };

        $scope.clearLine = function(){
            ScanService.dispatch(String("00" + $rootScope.lineData.lineNumber).slice(-2) + 'DONE');
        };

        $scope.removeStationItems = function (stationdID, createdDateTime){
            var url = config.baseURL + "/runner/removeDesktopRunnerItem/" + stationdID + "/" + createdDateTime.split(' ').join('_') + "/" + $sessionStorage.user.loginName;
            $http.get(url).then(function(response){
                if(response.status === 200 && response.statusText === "OK"){
                    var data = response.data;
                    if(data === ''){
                        $state.go($rootScope.prevState);
                        $rootScope.setObjects(data);
                        filterObjects();
                    }else{
                        $rootScope.setObjects(data);
                        filterObjects();
                        var found = $filter('getByStationID')(data.runnerItems, $rootScope.lineData.lineNumber);
                        if(found === null){
                            $state.go($rootScope.prevState);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        };

    })

.controller('queue', function ($rootScope, $http, $filter, $scope, config, $interval, $ionicLoading) {

        $rootScope.setObjects = function (data){
            $rootScope.runnerItemsPW = $filter('filter')(data.runnerItems,  {areaShort: "PW"});
            $rootScope.lineCountPW = $filter('filter')(data.lineCounts,  {areaShort: "PW"});
            $rootScope.runnerItemsRE = $filter('filter')(data.runnerItems,  {areaShort: "RE"});
            $rootScope.lineCountRE = $filter('filter')(data.lineCounts,  {areaShort: "RE"});
            $rootScope.runnerItemsNC = $filter('filter')(data.runnerItems,  {areaShort: "NC"});
            $rootScope.lineCountNC = $filter('filter')(data.lineCounts,  {areaShort: "NC"});
            $rootScope.runnerItemsSP = $filter('filter')(data.runnerItems,  {areaShort: "SP"});
            $rootScope.lineCountSP = $filter('filter')(data.lineCounts,  {areaShort: "SP"});
          };

    });
```

When the controller is first started the `$scope.items` is added to the object and works just fine. The line `$scope.items` is updated when new data comes in. However, the ng-repeat I have for `lineData.items` does not update.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Not enough shown to diagnose any problems

Comment: Added code for each controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only assigning to `$rootScope.lineData` once, in the controller initialization function. This function only gets called once, during the bootstrap process.

You need to assign it in your `filterObjects` function as well so that it gets updated by your `$http` call. This means that you need to create it before calling `filterObjects` the first time. Like this:

```
$rootScope.lineData = {
    position: 1,
    lineNumber: $stateParams.line,
    area: $stateParams.area,
    areaName: areaName,
    lineCounts: lineCounts,
};

function filterObjects () {
    switch ($stateParams.area) {
        case 'PW':
            $rootScope.lineData.items = $scope.items = $filter('filter')($rootScope.runnerItemsPW, {line: $stateParams.line}, true);
            areaName = "Putwall";
            lineCounts = $rootScope.lineCountPW;
            break;
        // etc.
    }
}

filterObjects();
```

Answer (score 1):

$filter creates a new object so need to updated $rootScope.lineData. Update the $rootScope.lineData again after filter.

Comment: Alright, would you be able to provide an example. I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and I am stumped.

Comment: Let me create plunkr. Give me some time.

Comment: Check the answer by Jack. he is doing the same thing. Basically, $filter is creating a new object so you need to reassign it to $rootScope.lineData.Items

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking the original object reference when you reassign `$scope.items` so the original reference passed to the lineData object is no longer the same as the array referenced by `$scope.items`

Simple example

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];

var obj={
   items: myArray // reference to array above 
}
console.log(myArray ); // [1,2,3]
console.log(obj.items); // [1,2,3] - exact same object reference as myArray

// now reassign myArray with new object reference 
myArray =[6,7,8];

console.log(myArray ); // [6,7,8]
console.log(obj.items); // [1,2,3] - the original reference hasn't changed

// now reassign object property value to new array
obj.items = myArray ;
console.log(obj.items); // [6,7,8] - references new array
```

NOTE:  you should be using a service to share data and methods across controllers.

Answer (score -2):

In $http response code add line $scope.$apply(); after calling function filterObjects()

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, I receive an injector error.

Comment: It already gets called internally and this will cause `digest in progress` error. Issue in OP code is about breaking object references.